# Laravel mysql php Timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to count unread messages in laravel app, however my "last_viewed" column contains "raw" time in seconds stored in "last_viewed (int) 11"  and my "created_at" contains mysql timestamp so I can't compare them in mysql statement. Here is how I compare them, but it's kind of spaghetti

```html
class Helper {

 public static function count_unread_messages()
 {
          $result = Conversation::join('messages','messages.conversation_id','=','conversation.id')
                  ->join('conversation_members','conversation_members.conversation_id','=','conversation.id')
                  ->select('conversation_members.last_viewed as last_viewed',
                   'messages.created_at as created_at')
                  ->where('conversation_members.user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
                  ->groupBy('messages.id')->get();
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($result as $key) {
       if (date($key->last_viewed) < date(strtotime($key->created_at))) {
        $i++;
       }   
  }
  return $i;
 }
}
```

but I'd like to compare inside Mysql statement, like that 
->where('last_viewed' ,'<', 'created_at')->count()

Is there a way to change format of a timestamp into seconds inside a mysql statement?

Comment: The function you're looking for is called ``FROM_UNIXTIME()``, see documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime. You're going to have to use ``DB::raw()`` statements, by the way. Good luck! :)

Comment: thank You, but FROM_UNIXTIME() converts seconds into timestamp, is there a function which converts timestamps into seconds?

Comment: The reverse is called ``UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`` - documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp. Although you can compare either seconds or dates directly, it'll result in the same thing. That said, do you really store in timestamp - not in datetime?

Comment: Yes I store 'created_at' in timestamp(it requiered by laravel 4) and 'last_viewed' in int11 seconds, however when I compare dates it gives me some random results, so I prefer comparing in seconds

Comment: Fair enough. I'd forgotten Laravel doesn't use datetime.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to solve this is to persist time stamps as [carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) instances.

You can do that by setting `protected $dates = ['last_viewed', 'created_at'];` in your `Conversation` model.

Now when the data get persisted, since `last_viewed` and `created_at` persists as carbon instances and mainly because eloquent support carbon, you can simply achieve

`->where('last_viewed', '<', 'created_at')->count()` functionality.

Hope this was helpful.